# Red-Black Tree Height Proof

Tags: red-black-trees

I know that the height of a red-black tree is at most 2 lg(n + 1). However, what is the mathematical proof of this? I searched various sites, however I couldn't find a good proof. I already know the properties of a red-black tree.

Comment: "I already know the properties of a red-black tree." So you know the relationship between red-black trees and 2-3-4 trees?

Comment: I meant I know the 5 cases that must be true for the red-black tree to be a red-black tree. Every node must be red or black, every leaf is black, etc...

Comment: Right. Red-black trees were invented by Guibas and Sedgewick as a way to represent 2-3-4 trees (or 2-4 symmetric B-trees if you prefer). Every black node represents the root of a 2-3-4 tree node, and every red node represents the rest of a 2-3-4 tree node. So look up 2-3-4 trees and convince yourself that THEY are balanced first.